# Merging two data frames and keeping the extra rows from first df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames df1 and df2

df1

```
        A  B 
id0     a  3      
id1     b  4      
id2     c  0
```

df2

```
       A   B 
id2   aa  80      
id3   d   44      
id4   r   100
```

I want to join concat df1 and df2 in such a way that all rows of df1 are retained and if there are rows with the same index in df2( **id2 ; in this case** ); its dropped from df2.

Final df should look like

```
        A  B 
id0     a  3      
id1     b  4      
id2     c  0
id3     d   44      
id4     r   100
```

How can it be done in pandas python?

Regards

Comment: Is possible multiple duplicates index in `df1.index` or `df2.index` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), it is specifically designed for this operation:

```
df1.combine_first(df2)
```

output:

```
     A    B
id0  a    3
id1  b    4
id2  c    0
id3  d   44
id4  r  100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with filter first duplicates by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
print (df)
     A    B
id0  a    3
id1  b    4
id2  c    0
id3  d   44
id4  r  100
```