# Combining partially overlapping data frames on both axes pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to combine multiple data frames that partially overlap on both axes?
I came up already with a workable solution but I'm unsure it's the best way nor that I should be doing that at all.

So I have the following frames:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[6,6],[7,7]],columns=['a','b'])
print(df1)
   a  b
0  6  6
1  7  7
    
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[7,7],[8,8]],columns=['b','c'], index=[1,2])
print(df2)
   b  c
1  7  7
2  8  8
```

basically the only overlapping data point is b1

and I'd like to obtain the following:

```py
     a  b    c
0  6.0  6  NaN
1  7.0  7  7.0
2  NaN  8  8.0
```

If I do a regular concat I end up either with a duplicate on the index or on the columns. Now, the workaround I found is the following:

```py
dfc = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
dfc = dfc.groupby(dfc.index).mean()
print(dfc)
     a  b    c
0  6.0  6  NaN
1  7.0  7  7.0
2  NaN  8  8.0
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do it and more in general if this is best practice when handling data.
I should also add that in my datasets the overlapping data is always an exact duplicate and I "should" never have different values if the indexes are the same.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df1.combine_first(df2)
```

output:

```
     a  b    c
0  6.0  6  NaN
1  7.0  7  7.0
2  NaN  8  8.0
```

*NB. if b1 is different in the two dataframes, this will take the value from `df1`*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719413/merging-two-data-frames-and-keeping-the-extra-rows-from-first-df/69719535#69719535

Comment: Maybe should be wiki.

Comment: Sure, (I forgot I already answered the same thing ^^)

Comment: Hi great answer, thank you! So if I have several data frame to combine I'll just iterate and keep adding them to the final one right?

Comment: Yes, if you really have many you might want to use `functools.reduce` or a function wrapper

Comment: perfect, thanks again! That was really helpful